# Connecting multiple pairs of widgets in PyQt5

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I have multiple QSliders, QSpinBox pairs in my GUI which values I need to lock together.

Currently, this is how I implement it:

```
self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_slider_move)
self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.on_spinbox_val_change)

def on_slider_move(self, val):
   self.spinBox.setValue(val)

def on_spinbox_val_change(self, val):
   self.slider.setValue(val)
```

Assuming 5 (QSlider, QSpinBox) pairs, I must set 10 connections and 10 slots, with some slots performing minor changes to `val`.

There must be some generalized approach for this. For example, knowing who sent the signal and routing it accordingly to a specific slot:

```
def on_slider_move(self, sender, val):
   if sender == 'slider1':
       self.spinBox1.setValue(val)
   elif sender == 'slider2':
       self.spinBox2.setValue(val / 10)
   .
   .
   .
```

Unfortunately, I can't find a way to get the sender when connecting signals to slots.

What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `self` object has a `sender` method.

Call below function and you can use the logic what you have said in question.

```
sender = self.sender()
```